# SQL send query to email via msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail: single quotes error.

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

Within the below's `@query` field, I specify my query by using ' at the start and end. The block below works.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'SendCallCenter',
    @recipients = 'person@email.edu',
    @subject = 'Previous_No_Shows',
    @query = 
    N'Select
        [NETEWLifePRODDBV1.8.7].[dbo].[tblClient].[fldFirstName],[fldLastName],[fldLocation],[fldJHEDId], 
        [NETEWLifePRODDBV1.8.7].[dbo].[tblClientSchedule].[fldDuration],[fldDate]
    FROM 
        [NETEWLifePRODDBV1.8.7].[dbo].[tblClientSchedule] Inner Join [NETEWLifePRODDBV1.8.7].[dbo].[tblClient]
    on
        [NETEWLifePRODDBV1.8.7].[dbo].[tblClientSchedule].[fldClientId]= [NETEWLifePRODDBV1.8.7].[dbo].[tblClient].[fldClientId]
   WHERE
        [fldApptOutcomeId] = 4;',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Data.csv'
```

However when I introduce two new datetime parameters in `WHERE`, the ' within these lines interrupts the string at the numerical values.

[image]

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '17530101'.
```

What can I use to keep the entire query as a continuous string?

[I used this tutorial](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/send-query-results-sql-server-agent-job/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape your single quotes.

```
`..dd,''17530101'',getdate()....`
```

When you do it correctly, you won't see the dates in blue. Another great debugging tip is to set your query to a parameter

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select ...'
```

And then you can print it out, to make sure your concatenations, converts, etc worked.

```
print @sql
```

For example:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select datediff(dd,''17530101'',getdate())'
print @sql
```

You can also use the `@sql` in your proc execution by setting `@query = @sql` once you know that query string is correct.